# Is it possible to recursively chain generic functions?

Tags: java

Given I have the following code:

```java
var output = chain(
        0,
        n -> n + "hi",
        n -> n,
        n -> n + 1,
        n -> n.equals("0hi1")
);
```

How can I make the method accept an arbitrary amount of functions?

I know I can do this:

```java
public static <A, B, C, D, E> E chain(
        A val,
        Function<? super A, ? extends B> f1,
        Function<? super B, ? extends C> f2,
        Function<? super C, ? extends D> f3,
        Function<? super D, ? extends E> f4
) {
    return f4.apply(f3.apply(f2.apply(f1.apply(val))));
}
```

But that severely limits the amount of inputs.

Is there some recursive function I could write, something that accepts varargs maybe?

Something like this:

```java
public static OutputType chain(
        InputType val,
        Function<?, ?>... functions
) {
    var nextInput = functions[0].apply(val);
    if (functions.length == 1) return nextInput;
    var tail = Arrays.copyOfRange(functions, 1, functions.length);
    return chain(nextInput, tail);
}
```

I am aware that I can create a monad, or use streams, or use optional to chain transformations as such:

```java
var output = Optional
        .of(0)
        .map(n -> n + "hi")
        .map(n -> n)
        .map(n -> n + 1)
        .map(n -> n.equals("0hi1"))
        .get();
```

But I specifically DO NOT WANT TO do that. I want to achieve the style visible in that 1st code block.

Comment: Ah, varargs lambdas, we meet again. In this case the answer is **no**, it is not possible. The method invocation per resolution of `Function<T, R>` is strictly necessary, as those type parameters must be resolved at the call-site of the function. If you want your solution to work, you could make numerous hand-coded overloads for each number of functions possible (up to some sane limit, say 10 or 26), and keep them in some utility file. But at that point I'm not seeing an advantage over your other proposed solutions. Keep in mind you can make your own chainable method like `Optional` did.

Comment: I will say, that your first example would actually be possible with using just the same type on all lambdas. I'll write a small answer for that.

Comment: Only if every input and output have the same types, I don't want to be locked into just one specific input and one output type.

Comment: @Rogue Thanks, I am aware I can make my own chain able method, that's what a monad is in that sentence's context.

Comment: Note things like `n -> n.equals("0hi1")` wouldn't work, but you could `chain(...).equals("0hi1");` to get that `boolean`.

Comment: What is your use case for this?  What problem are you trying to solve where you need this capability?  It sounds like an  [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info)

Comment: Rogue's first comment answered the question correctly: the answer is no, this is not possible.

Comment: "Something like this:" - did you **try it**? What happened when you tried it?

Comment: @WJS The question is purely academic, it's not in a context of a problem because the problem is whether it's possible to achieve that syntax.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel It complains that wildcard cannot be assigned to Object

Comment: Right; the problem is that the recursion cannot work because it does not know what type will be returned, and therefore it cannot verify that the next step in the recursion makes any sense. For this kind of function composition to work, you need an `InputType` result at each step except possibly the last, and then special-casing the last step is not feasible.

Answer (score 1):

With the assumption that *all* functions in the call are of the same type, then it can be done with a simple generic type on the method:

```
public static <T> T chain(
        T val,
        Function<T, T>... functions
) {
    if (functions.length == 0) return val;
    var nextInput = functions[0].apply(val);
    if (functions.length == 1) return nextInput;
    var tail = Arrays.copyOfRange(functions, 1, functions.length);
    return chain(nextInput, tail);
}
```

There are other improvements that could be made (e.g. just using an index counter for the recursion to avoid array copies, or not being recursive). Be extra careful of boundary conditions, e.g. passing an empty call.

Using this, you may use any type for the input, and the functions will require operating on the same input and output types.

Answer (score 1):

> *"Is it possible to recursively chain generic functions? ...*
>
> *... How can I make the method accept an arbitrary amount of functions? ..."*

Your example will suffice, just utilize a *raw generic*; un-parameterized.

There's no reason to define a parameter if you're intending to use a *wildcard generic* with *A*, *B*, *C*, and *D*.

*[Raw Types (The Java™ Tutorials > Learning the Java Language > Generics (Updated))](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/rawTypes.html)*.

This will discourage a plausible overhead to the *functions* array, and will provide fully restricted access to *val* within *chain*.

```java
@SuppressWarnings({"rawtypes", "unchecked"})
public Object chain(Object val, Function ... functions) {
    Object nextInput = functions[0].apply(val);
    if (functions.length == 1) return nextInput;
    Function[] tail = Arrays.copyOfRange(functions, 1, functions.length);
    return chain(nextInput, tail);
}
```

Here is a usage.
I had to *cast* the third function here, *n*'s type is otherwise ambiguous.

```java
var output = chain(
    0,
    n ->n +"hi",
    n ->n,
    (Function<String, ?>) n ->n +1,
    n ->n.equals("0hi1")
);
```

Output

```
true
```

> *"... Is there some recursive function I could write, something that accepts varargs maybe? ..."*

Considering you are passing a modified *array* for each recursive *chain* call, I'd recommend creating a class.
Here you can provide a dynamic list of values, to a set of recursive *chain* calls.

```java
@SuppressWarnings({"rawtypes", "unchecked"})
public Object chain(Object val, Function ... functions) {
    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes, unchecked")
    class Chain {
        Object x;
        List<Function> list = new ArrayList<>();

        Chain(Object x, Function ... functions) {
            this.x = x;
            list.addAll(List.of(functions));
            chain();
        }

        void chain() {
            x = list.get(0).apply(x);
            if (list.size() == 1) return;
            list.remove(0);
            chain();
        }

        Object get() {
            return x;
        }
    }
    return new Chain(val, functions).get();
}
```